# Type unable to index object with key of type number

Tags: typescript

```
const typeLevels = {
  "INTJ": {
    1: ["INFJ", "ENFP", "INTP", "ENTJ"],
    2: ["INFP", "ENFJ", "ISTP", "ESTJ"],
    3: ["ISFP", "ESFJ", "ISTJ", "ESTP"],
    4: ["ISFJ", "ESFP"],
  },
  ...
}

const notRandomNumbers: number[] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3];

const userKey: keyof typeof typeLevels = user!.data()!["personalityScore"]["type"];

const userMap: {1: string[], 2: string[], 3: string[], 4: string[]} = typeLevels[userKey];
      
const userOneLevelIndex: keyof typeof userMap = Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length);
```

This code gives me error `Type 'number' is not assignable to type '1 | 2 | 3 | 4'.ts(2322)`

However, if I change `userOneLevelIndex` to `1` the error goes away. I realize I'm missing something but I don't understand what.

Comment: The compiler can only infer that the value will be a number, not that it will be in the range 1-4 (actually it will be 0-3...). In general, when you have more information than the compiler, [tell it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

Comment: Also what is `userKey` ?

Comment: @FiniteLooper Updated to show `userKey`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Updated to show `typeLevels` and `userKey`

Comment: Thanks. What are you trying to do with `userOneLevelIndex`? What's the overall goal here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keyof typeof userMap` is the type `1 | 2 | 3 | 4`, which is a union of [number literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). It's *more specific* than `number`. It only allows the literal types `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`, specifically, not all numbers. But `Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length)` returns `number`. You can't assign `number` to the more restrictive `1 | 2 | 3 | 4` type. (And in terms of runtime correctness, you also have the problem that that random expression will give you any value from `0` to `9`, inclusive, since `notRandomNumbers.length` is `10`. But trying to use `0` or `5` through `9` inclusive with `userOneLevelIndex` is incorrect, as `userMap` only has properties for `1` to `4`, inclusive.)

It's not clear what you're trying to do with the random value, but I *think* you may have meant to use it to index into `notRandomNumbers` and then use the resulting value, rather than using the index directly as a key for `userMap`. If so, you can tell TypeScript that the values in `notRandomNumbers` aren't going to change and let it infer a more specific type for the values in the array:

```typescript
const notRandomNumbers = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3] as const;
```

The type of `notRandomNumbers` will now be a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) containing number literals, and so `typeof notRandomNumbers[number]` will be `1 | 2 | 3`, and using one of those values as `userOneLevelIndex` is valid:

```typescript
const userOneLevelIndex: keyof typeof userMap = notRandomNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length)];
```

That means this works:

```typescript
console.log(userMap[userOneLevelIndex]); // <== Works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgGWQN2QGwjAvDAN4CwAUDJTAJIByAKgFIBcx5VHMAjKwNoBEdAGKN+AGhj8AorSEAFcZLr0FE6Q1EBdMe06UATH0GzVkmSMWCAyistSbWnRT0wAzEepX5dr6LWemH1ttXT0AFg9fH28Q50oAXycOAHpkmAA6TPJ4gG5yclBIWDAQKAAlAEMwABMQAFtaAFc6gCNkACc8Ql4uCV7uPsGYfQkR4dGJV00YCrxC6DyyAvBoGEaIDoBpZHhWAGsdkAAzOCRkY9OUdCxcAkloKuqAWgBLMCfqiqgK-hm8KvgORgqXWHQAhOlPt8ABQASjBAhQnXAFWwLwQVlA7WQ-E0AgQKFxi2WRTWG3aAFkKohWERuKxoO03gBzXiaIGGGCMllsoHuLlQJlgVnsmARAVCkUweJ3AloTA4CC8UHtbbwdn5MjzWAqgDyYHlN2oNWQAA99ocTnKLiqqYg7iVyo96k1Wh0lVSoAALdJHbAgEDtaGen3tZ11OEwABUMEdlRqLuabU66WwyGF3th7KAA)

You don't need the explicit type annotation on that, though:

```typescript
const userOneLevelIndex = notRandomNumbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length)];
console.log(userMap[userOneLevelIndex]); // <== Works
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCeAHApgGWQN2QGwjAvDAN4CwAUDJTAJIByAKgFIBcx5VHMAjKwNoBEdAGKN+AGhj8AorSEAFcZLr0FE6Q1EBdMe06UATH0GzVkmSMWCAyistSbWnRT0wAzEepX5dr6LWemH1ttXT0AFg9fH28Q50oAXycOAHpkmAA6TPJ4gG5yclBIWDAQKAAlAEMwABMQAFtaAFc6gCNkACc8Ql4uCV7uPsGYfQkR4dGJV00YCrxC6DyyAvBoGEaIDoBpZHhWAGsdkAAzOCRkY9OUdCxcAkloKuqAWgBLMCfqiqgK-hm8KvgORgqXWHQAhOlPt8ABQASjBAhQnXAFWwLwQVlA7WQ-E0AgQKFxi2WRTWG3aAFkKohWERuKxoO03gBzXiaIGGGCMllsoHuLlQJlgVnsmARAVCkUweJ3AloTA4CC8UHtbbwdn5MjzWAqgDyYHlN2oNWQAA87iVyo96k1Wh0lVSoAALdJHbAgEDtaGOl3ta11OEwABUMEtlRqNuabU66WwyGFzthGq1KxAcdjIGZ0JVVMQyvJ+sNOGN1TNmlhQNSMAAPPhCAB1T17CBAA)

Answer (score 0):

You don't define what `typeLevels` or `userkey` are in your question.  However, just remove that 2nd line of code entirely seems to make things work just fine.  I'm not really sure what you are tying to do here though.

```
const notRandomNumbers: number[] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3];
const userOneLevelIndex= Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length);
```

if you are just tying to tell TypeScript that the numbers can only be between 1 and 4, then just use that in your typedef like this:

```
type numLimit = 1|2|3|4;
const notRandomNumbers: numLimit[] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3];
const userOneLevelIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * notRandomNumbers.length);
```